# Quebra de linha excessiva ao criar arquivo .txt C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, txt

Estou tentando gerar um arquivo `.txt` a partir de uma lista de códigos recuperada do banco de dados. Entretanto, quando o arquivo é gerado, as quebras de linhas saem em número excessivo, conforme imagem abaixo:

> [image: Arquivo .txt gerado]

O código está conforme abaixo, sendo um foreach que percorre toda a lista de objetos recuperada do banco e escreve cada código no arquivo .txt:

```
using (StreamWriter linha = System.IO.File.CreateText(caminhoArquivo))

     foreach(var item in codigos)
     {
        linha.Write(item + "\r\n");
     }


return File(caminhoArquivo, "text/plain", nomeArquivo);
```

Para a quebra de linha, além do `"\r\n"`, já tentei utilizar linha.**WriteLine**(item) e linha.`**Write**(item + *Enviroment.NewLine*)`, e outras variações. entretanto, o problema persistiu.

Alguém sabe como resolvo o mesmo?

Comment: O problema parece estar no conteúdo, deve estar cheio de itens sem nada em `codigos`.

Comment: faz um if para verificar se o item não está vazio antes de imprimi-lo

Comment: Ou usa o `item.Trim()` antes de por ele.

Answer (score 3):

Um if a validar a existência de conteúdo bastará.

```
using (StreamWriter linha = System.IO.File.CreateText(caminhoArquivo))

    foreach(var item in codigos){
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item){
            linha.Write(item + "\r\n");
        }
    }

return File(caminhoArquivo, "text/plain", nomeArquivo);
```

Answer (score 3):

Como dito pelo Maniero nos comentários, o problema estava que itens nulos estavam sendo retornados na busca do banco. A principio, estava buscando os itens e recuperando os códigos com a seguinte consulta:

```
        {
        var vendidos = (from c in _dbContext.VendaCoupon where c.DataVenda.Year == anoReferencia && c.DataVenda.Month == mesReferencia && c.Cancelado == false select c).ToList();

        List<string> codigos = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in vendidos)
        {
            var getCodigo = (from c in _dbContext.Coupon where c.IdCoupon == item.IdCoupon && c.IdTipoCoupon == 4 select c.Codigo).FirstOrDefault();

            codigos.Add(getCodigo);
        }

        return codigos;
    }
```

Para solucionar, fiz um *join* entre as duas tabelas e retornei o resultado da busca. Dessa forma, os itens nulos pararam de ser retornados:

```
        {
        var vendidos = (from c in _dbContext.VendaCoupon join b in _dbContext.Coupon on c.IdCoupon equals b.IdCoupon where c.DataVenda.Year == anoReferencia && c.DataVenda.Month == mesReferencia && c.Cancelado == false && b.IdTipoCoupon == 4 select b.Codigo).ToList();

        return vendidos;
    }
```

Comment: É uma opção válida, mas dependendo do número de registos, poderá não ser a mais performativa. um join pode ser uma operação bastante pesada e menos eficiente caso não existam index's apropriados em caso de elevado número de registos.